# Automated browser compatibility validation

Tags: unit-testing, validation, cross-browser

Even though the HTML/CSS page is 100% valid according to http://validator.w3.org/
the page may still be broken in some browsers (*cough* IE7 *cough*).

Is there a unittest / validation tool that parses the html, css and javascript and searches the DOM for known browser bugs. Like using "position: relative" in combination with jQuery.slideUp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's hard with static analysis.  You could have `position: relative` in a class you applied via an event handler to several elements, one of which you later selected by id and called `slideUp()` on.  The validation tool you want would need the facilities of a browser *and*  need to trigger all kinds of events to find those dangerous patterns.

Because Microsoft browsers are so excellent and are likely to give you a handful of new problems no one else has ever encountered before, it's hard to avoid spending time testing by hand; and on your way to finding crashes they crafted just for you, you'll catch the more mundane ones.

Comment: Only way i can think of to get it working is to create a Firebug extension that analyses a live DOM.